# check url pattern using js

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have been looking around to find a way to oblige the visitors to write a url in a field. The pattern has to be **www.domain.com**

I don't want any other pattern

```
     function is_url(str) {

                            regexp =  /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
                                    if (regexp.test(str))
                                    {
                                    return true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    return false;
                                    }
                            }
```

The code above embeded in a function does not seem to work. 
would appreciate any help 
Thanks

Comment: HTML 5 has a built in url type: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_url.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you **just** want URLs that begin with www. and end with .com with valid domain name between (A-Z, or a-z, or 0-9, or a hyphen symbol, length between 3 and 63 inclusive) then try this regex:

```
www\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,63}\.com
```

[You can test it here.](https://regex101.com/r/n3SP3F/1)